# Fedora 20 : Removing domain info (converted to hyphens)

Tags: hostname, fedora-20

Im noticing that in Fedora 20, if I modify the HOSTNAME=.... parameter to include a typical hostname:

```
HOSTNAME=machine1.local
```

It actually replaces the "." with a "-" character , and machine1.local is not pingable.

Why is fedora interchanging the "." character with a dash, given that the "." in a hostname has a very specific meaning, and is usually deliberate?

And my more important question: Whats the right way to set a fully qualified hostname on a local computer (I dont have DNS set up).

Comment: What `HOSTNAME` parameter? From where?

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL 7 and recent Fedora, the system hostname is no longer set in the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file. It is now set in the `/etc/hostname` file, which should contain *only* the fully qualified domain name.

```
# cat /etc/hostname
saurok.example.com
#
```